# How can I get the title attribute of the current anchor being hovered?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Have ~500 anchor tags in a grid that all have title attributes, I would like to get that title from the element the user is currently hovering, and display it at the top of the grid so you can tell what you are hovering over. Or, is there an alternative?

```
<a class="color" title="#Wicked" style="height: 30px; width: 30px; background-color: rgb(70, 60, 65); display: block;"></a>
<a class="color" title="#Tallulah" style="height: 30px; width: 30px; background-color: rgb(95, 58, 61); display: block;"></a>
<a class="color" title="#Merlot" style="height: 30px; width: 30px; background-color: rgb(79, 56, 57); display: block;"></a>
<a class="color" title="#Speakeasy" style="height: 30px; width: 30px; background-color: rgb(87, 50, 65); display: block;"></a>
<a class="color" title="#Tamarind" style="height: 30px; width: 30px; background-color: rgb(95, 68, 74); display: block;"></a>
<a class="color" title="#Oxford" style="height: 30px; width: 30px; background-color: rgb(101, 64, 60); display: block;"></a>
<a class="color" title="#Mulberry" style="height: 30px; width: 30px; background-color: rgb(111, 70, 83); display: block;"></a>
<a class="color" title="#Crantini" style="height: 30px; width: 30px; background-color: rgb(128, 81, 87); display: block;"></a>
<a class="color" title="#Sangria" style="height: 30px; width: 30px; background-color: rgb(121, 87, 90); display: block;"></a>
<a class="color" title="#Pueblo" style="height: 30px; width: 30px; background-color: rgb(141, 108, 109); display: block;"></a>
<a class="color" title="#Bel Ange Rose" style="height: 30px; width: 30px; background-color: rgb(167, 123, 127); display: block;"></a>
<a class="color" title="#Foxglove" style="height: 30px; width: 30px; background-color: rgb(200, 143, 120); display: block;"></a>
<a class="color" title="#Cactus Bloom" style="height: 30px; width: 30px; background-color: rgb(230, 191, 164); display: block;"></a>
<a class="color" title="#Pillow Talk" style="height: 30px; width: 30px; background-color: rgb(240, 221, 211); display: block;"></a>
```

Can't seem to find any way to grab this, yet. Any tips or alternatives helpful!

Demo [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/subhash9/5c6ut/)

Comment: Those link tag  shoudln't be have a title with an anchor but an href

Comment: `.color { width: 30px; height: 30px; display: block; }`? :)

Comment: Yes, exactly what @Stefan said! I was just about to post an updated fiddle which *styles* the *style* properties.  see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/5c6ut/1/) for a much cleaner implementation.

Comment: @Stefan Of course :) It was just to make it easy for you guys to understand otherwise y'all would write more code! Thanks for watching out for me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding to what's already been posted here, you should move as much style information into CSS as possible.  Taking @Rory McCrossan suggestion, if you put the whole thing inside of a container, then we can use that to style just the color elements with the following **css**

```css
#colors a {
    height: 30px;
    width: 30px;
    display: block;
}
```

Then our **HTML** should look like this:

```html
<div id='currentColor'>Color: </div>
<div id='colors'>
    <a title="Wicked" style="background-color: rgb(70, 60, 65);"/>
    <!-- more colors -->
</div>
```

We can do the rest with **js/jQuery**.

```js
$('#colors').on({
    mouseenter: function () {
        $('#currentColor').text("Color: " + this.title);
    },
    mouseleave: function () {
        $('#currentColor').text("Color: ");
    }
}, 'a');
```

This code uses jQuery's [**`on`**](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method to attach a [`delegated handler`](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events) to `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events for all `a` elements inside the `#colors` container.

See this demo:

## [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FnF6F/2/)

Comment: **Great!** This is a very complete answer, thank you for all of your tips.

Answer (score 9):

Try this:

```
$('.color').mouseover(function() {
    var title = this.title;
    // do something with title...
});
```

---

As you have 500 elements, you could use a single delegated handler to improve performance. Firstly wrap your elements in a containing `div`:

```
<div id="container">
    <!-- your current code here -->
</div>
```

Then in jQuery:

```
$('#container').on('mouseover', '.color', function() {
    var title = this.title;
    console.log(title);
});
```

This will result in 1 element having an event handler instead of potentially 500.

Comment: @JasonP good point. I missed the fact there were 500 of them, editing now.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Thank you so much, your noting that there would be 500 handlers prevented some nasty-ness.

Answer (score 1):

[here](http://jsfiddle.net/VFZLS/) is the solution to your problem on jsfiddle

and below is the code

```
$('a').mouseover(function(){
    alert($(this).prop('title'));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use the following code:

```
$('.color').hover(function(){

var title = $(this).attr("title");    

});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("a:hover").mouseenter(function(){
   var _title = $(this).attr("title"); // Why prefix with an anchor? Maybe you need to replace....
   console.log(_title);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is cleaned Html,Css and Script  **[Jsfiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/ML79V/)**

```
<div class="container">
<a class="color" title="#Wicked" style=" background-color: rgb(70, 60, 65); "></a>
<a class="color" title="#Tallulah" style=" background-color: rgb(95, 58, 61); "></a>
<a class="color" title="#Merlot" style=" background-color: rgb(79, 56, 57); "></a>
<a class="color" title="#Speakeasy" style=" background-color: rgb(87, 50, 65); "></a>
<a class="color" title="#Tamarind" style=" background-color: rgb(95, 68, 74); "></a>
<a class="color" title="#Oxford" style=" background-color: rgb(101, 64, 60); "></a>
<a class="color" title="#Mulberry" style=" background-color: rgb(111, 70, 83); "></a>
<a class="color" title="#Crantini" style=" background-color: rgb(128, 81, 87); "></a>
<a class="color" title="#Sangria" style=" background-color: rgb(121, 87, 90); "></a>
<a class="color" title="#Pueblo" style=" background-color: rgb(141, 108, 109); "></a>
<a class="color" title="#Bel Ange Rose" style=" background-color: rgb(167, 123, 127); "></a>
<a class="color" title="#Foxglove" style=" background-color: rgb(200, 143, 120); "></a>
<a class="color" title="#Cactus Bloom" style=" background-color: rgb(230, 191, 164); "></a>
<a class="color" title="#Pillow Talk" style=" background-color: rgb(240, 221, 211); "></a>
</div>
```

**Script**

```
 $('.color').on('mouseenter',function() {
        alert(this.title);
    });
```

**Css**

```
.color{height: 30px; width: 30px;display:block;}
.container{width:50%;margin:0 auto;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap has some pretty sweet looking tooltips: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tooltips

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $('a').tooltip();
    </script>
```

Demo http://jsfiddle.net/wernull/fEzsy/

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I'll look into it for future projects(can't use bootstrap here)